# Windows vista setup error code 0x0000001e when installing to GPT partition

Tags: windows-vista

Basically i installed windows 10,7,8.1,11 on my Asus laptop. But when i try to install windows vista, after the first restart it gives me BSOD and error code:

```
0x0000001e (0xFFFFFFFFC0000005, 0xFFFFF8000AC716A7,0x0000000000000000,0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
```

and nothing else.
I tried searching solutions on Google and learned that windows 8 and 10 cause this. The laptop came preinstalled with windows 8 but later upgraded to 10.

Should I just give up or is there a fix for this?

Comment: The error descriptions I see relate to driver and hardware errors. Vista is LONG out of support and will not run on a new machine. Vista WILL run in a VM .....  I have it running here.

Comment: I am confused,  are you downgrading your laptop to Vista

Comment: Why do i need to, I just multi-booting

Answer (score 2):

I think a better approach at this point, is to solve this problem with Virtual Machines and not multiple boot.

I have VMware Workstation V17 running on a Windows 11 Pro Host.

This runs:  Windows 10 Pro, Windows 7 Pro and Windows Vista Business.

I had no need for Windows 8 but it, too, will run as a Virtual Machine Guest.

Everything you wish to do including Windows Vista can be solved this way and I highly recommend it to you.

So I recommend you use Virtual Machines as a better overall strategy for those machines you wish to run.

If you wish to remain with a multiple boot system, you will have to give up on Vista and everything prior.

Comment: Will something Change if i delete windows 8

Comment: No.   Vista is so old it will not run on your computer. So either convert to VMs or leave Vista behind. I posted both strategies in my answer

Comment: Will it not run because of drivers or laptop specs?

Comment: Drivers are old and the hardware is new . So you simply cannot multi boot Vista or anything prior on your computer.

Comment: Even if i theoretically try to update them?

Comment: Just about no chance of that. New machines leave old machines and old drivers behind. There is nothing you can do about it .

Comment: Wait what if i try to install windows 7 beta build

Comment: You can only try, but I do not think that will work to get Vista going. You said you had Windows 7 running as multi boot

Comment: Going forward (a year or two) Virtual Machines is simply a more strategic approach. Why not use that?

Comment: I use VM's alot but i will try to install the milestone 1 build of windows 7

Comment: Because you have Windows 11 you must install everything else in UEFI mode and GPT (Windows in UEFI mode strictly requires it). **Vista does NOT support UEFI mode or GPT**. That's the error you got and is to be expected. The oldest Windows version that can be installed in UEFI mode was 7 with the latest service pack. What you want to do for absolutely no practical reason can't be done, period. Please don't persist in using comments in a Q&A like in a forum. This isn't a forum. You have your answer, if useful please accept it. Otherwise please respect other users' time and volunteer efforts.